# Console Blackjack c#, adding totals

Tags: c#, blackjack

Our intro to coding professor wanted us to create a blackjack game using arrays in c#. We are having trouble with adding the values of our "hit card" to our initial totals. When we try to hit multiple times, all it does is replace the first "hit card" and only adds the new one to the initial total.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack_Midterm
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //set up multidementional array for card values
        string[,] cards = new string[52, 3]
                {
                    {"Hearts", "Ace", "1"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Ace", "1"},
                    {"Clubs", "Ace", "1"},
                    {"Spades", "Ace", "1"},
                    {"Hearts", "Two", "2"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Two", "2"},
                    {"Clubs", "Two", "2"},
                    {"Spades", "Two", "2"},
                    {"Hearts", "Three", "3"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Three", "3"},
                    {"Clubs", "Three", "3"},
                    {"Spades", "Three", "3"},
                    {"Hearts", "Four", "4"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Four", "4"},
                    {"Clubs", "Four", "4"},
                    {"Spades", "Four", "4"},
                    {"Hearts", "Five", "5"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Five", "5"},
                    {"Clubs", "Five", "5"},
                    {"Spades", "Five", "5"},
                    {"Hearts", "Six", "6"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Six", "6"},
                    {"Clubs", "Six", "6"},
                    {"Spades", "Six", "6"},
                    {"Hearts", "Seven", "7"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Seven", "7"},
                    {"Clubs", "Seven", "7"},
                    {"Spades", "Seven", "7"},
                    {"Hearts", "Eight", "8"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Eight", "8"},
                    {"Clubs", "Eight", "8"},
                    {"Spades", "Eight", "8"},
                    {"Hearts", "Nine", "9"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Nine", "9"},
                    {"Clubs", "Nine", "9"},
                    {"Spades", "Nine", "9"},
                    {"Hearts", "Ten", "10"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Ten", "10"},
                    {"Clubs", "Ten", "10"},
                    {"Spades", "Ten", "10"},
                    {"Hearts", "Jack", "10"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Jack", "10"},
                    {"Clubs", "Jack", "10"},
                    {"Spades", "Jack", "10"},
                    {"Hearts", "Queen", "10"},
                    {"Diamonds", "Queen", "10"},
                    {"Clubs", "Queen", "10"},
                    {"Spades", "Queen", "10"},
                    {"Hearts", "King", "10"},
                    {"Diamonds", "King", "10"},
                    {"Clubs", "King", "10"},
                    {"Spades", "King", "10"},
                };






        //Title and Rules of game
        Console.WriteLine("BlackJack with FlapJacks \n");
        Console.WriteLine("Rules: \n");
        Console.WriteLine("        - You are given two cards");
        Console.WriteLine("        - The Dealer is given two cards (One          Face-up, one Face-down)");
        Console.WriteLine("        - The object of the game is to get closest to 21 without going over");
        Console.WriteLine("                      - If you go over 21, it's game over");
        Console.WriteLine("                      - If you receive 21 on the first two cards, automatic win (applies to both the dealer and player) \n");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'ENTER' to begin \n");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Boolean Broke = false;

        int Chips;
        Chips = 100;

        while (Chips > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Remaining Chips: {0}", Chips);
            Console.Write("Place your bet(1-{0}): ", Chips);
            string bet = Console.ReadLine();
            int Bet = Convert.ToInt16(bet);
            Boolean Stand = false;

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            //Deal Cards out to player and Dealer
            Console.WriteLine("Dealing Cards \n");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("(Player's Hand) \n");

            //Set up a RNG to pick from the created arrays
            //Set up RNG for each card
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int card1 = rnd.Next(52);
            int card2 = rnd.Next(52);
            int card3 = rnd.Next(52);
            int card4 = rnd.Next(52);


            Console.WriteLine(cards[card1, 1] + " of " + cards[card1, 0]);



            card2 = rnd.Next(52);
            Console.WriteLine(cards[card2, 1] + " of " + cards[card2, 0]);


            int Value1 = Convert.ToInt16(cards[card1, 2]);
            int Value2 = Convert.ToInt16(cards[card2, 2]);
            int Total1 = Value1 + Value2;
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + Total1);


            Console.WriteLine("\n");


            Console.WriteLine("(Dealer's Hand) \n");
            //Show the first card
            card3 = rnd.Next(52);
            Console.WriteLine(cards[card3, 1] + " of " + cards[card3, 0]);

            //Second Card place holder
            card4 = rnd.Next(52);
            Console.WriteLine("[Hidden Card]");

            //Convert the values to integers
            //Add and show the total of the two cards
            int Value3 = Convert.ToInt16(cards[card3, 2]);
            int Value4 = Convert.ToInt16(cards[card4, 2]);
            int Total2 = Value3;
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + Total2);

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            while (Stand == false)
            {
                //Ask if Player wants to Hit or Stand
                Console.Write("Hit(1) or Stand(2)?: ");
                //Set up user input (string)
                string GuessAsAString = Console.ReadLine();
                //Convert String to an Int
                int Answer = Convert.ToInt16(GuessAsAString);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");


                if (Answer == 1)
                {
                    Stand = false;
                    //Continually add on to previous player total until     "stand" or "bust"
                    card2 = rnd.Next(52);
                    Console.WriteLine(cards[card2, 1] + " of " +    cards[card2, 0]);
                    int Value5 = Convert.ToInt16(cards [card2, 2]);
                    int Total3 = Total1 + Value5;
                    Console.WriteLine("Total: " + Total3);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                }

                else if (Answer == 2)
                {
                    Stand = true;
                }  
            }

            //Add cards to Dealer's hand until over 17 or bust
            Console.WriteLine("Dealing Dealer's hand");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);


            Console.WriteLine(cards[card4, 1] + " of " + cards[card4, 0]);



        }



        Console.ReadKey();














}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're never updating your initial total variable: `Total1` as part of your `while (Stand == false)` loop. Instead you are doing exactly as you describe: only adding the new card value to the initial value.

What you need to do is not re-declare `Total3` variable each time the stand loop iterates through. Move its declaration outside of the loop instead. For example:

```
int Total3 = Total1; // Intialise the running total with the inital value from the deal
while (Stand == false)
{
    ...

    Total3 = Total3 + Value5; // Add value of the newly dealt card to the running total.
    Console.WriteLine("Total: " + Total3);

    ...
}
```

I would also highly recommend to rename your variables better to improve readability of your code. Naming your variables `Total1`, `Total2`, etc. is not good practice and makes it harder to debug issues such as what you're experiencing right now. Make your variable names actually describe what they are for, e.g. instead of `Total3` name it `runningTotal`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! Also

Comment: Also, thank you for the advice on naming the variables. I am just beginning to learn code, so I haven't quite picked up on good technique for naming conventions. I will continue to work on that!

Comment: @ParkerSternberger, Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct.